# Use JavaScript to write string in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to pass some text into a hidden input when certain part of the page are clicked.

The simplest version of this (with input="text" to check if it works) would look like this :

```js
function myFunct(the_text) {
  document.getElementById('id01').value = the_text;
  return;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="id01" value="write here" />

<a href="#" onclick( "myFunct("this text should go on the box ");"); /> click me </a>
</br>
<a href="#" onclick( "myFunct("or this one ");"); /> No! Click me </a>
</br>
```

I don't know how to properly pass the string as the parameter of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try the below code:-

```
<input type="text" id="id01" value="write here" />

<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('this text should go on the box')" /> click me </a> </br>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('or this one ')" /> No! Click me </a> </br>

<script>
    function myFunct(the_text) {
        document.getElementById('id01').value = the_text;
    return;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this code is similar to the ones proposed above and it does work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You had some mistakes in your HTML code. It should be like `onclick="sth"`, instead of the brackets. I think I got the example working, check out the code below:

```html
<input type="text" id="id01" value="write here" />
<div id="id02"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('this text should go on the box')" /> click me </a> </br>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('or this one')" /> No! Click me </a> </br>

<script>
    function myFunct(the_text) {
        document.getElementById('id01').value = the_text;
        document.getElementById('id02').innerHTML = the_text;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunct(the_text) {
  $("#id01").val(the_text);
  return true;
  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="id01" value="write here" />

<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('this text should go on the box');" ); /> click me </a>
</br>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('or this one ');" ); /> No! Click me </a>
</br>
```

You had some mistakes in your HTML code. It should be like onclick="some function", instead of the brackets. I think I got the example working, check out the code below:
you jquery instead of javascript you will get the data

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing syntax between JavaScript and HTML.  The `onclick` you're trying to use is an HTML attribute like any other, and would take the form:

```
onclick=""
```

So your element might look something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('or this one ')" />
```

Note also the use of different quotes for the string.  JavaScript can use single-quotes or double-quotes, so by using single-quotes here it doesn't interfere with parsing the double-quoted HTML attribute.

---

Alternatively, you might remove the JavaScript from the HTML entirely.  Give your elements `id` values:

```
<a href="#" id="someID" /> click me </a> </br>
```

And use those to identify them for adding click handlers:

```
document.getElementById('someID').onclick = function()
{
    myFunct('or this one ');
};
```

The same approach can be used with jQuery (since you have that tag in the question).  Ideally you'd want to move in the general direction of separating markup from code, whether you use jQuery or not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused. The onclick must be an HTML syntax `onclick=`and used like this

```
onclick="myFunct('text')"
```

Try this:

```js
function myFunct(the_text) {
   alert(the_text);
        document.getElementById('id01').value = the_text;
    return;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="id01" value="write here" />

<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('this text should go on the box');" /> click me </a> 
</br>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('or this one');" /> No! Click me </a> </br>
```

Another option is to use JQuery "Who's your real girlfriend?" as an example.

```js
$("#me").click(function() {
  $("#target").text( "Sorry, he picked me." );
});

$("#otherme").click(function() {
  $("#target").text( "I know you'll choose me." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  Who's your real girlfriend?
</div>

</br>
<a href="#" id="me">Choose Me</a>
</br>
<a href="#" id="otherme">Please choose Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error.

```
<a href="#" onclick='myFunct("this text should go on the box")' /> click me </a> </br>
<a href="#" onclick='myFunct("or this one ")' /> No! Click me </a>
```